# Find factors of the numbers between 3 and 100 using PHP

Tags: php

I am a beginner in PHP and I am trying to find the factors between 2 and 10 of the numbers between 3 and 100. If it is prime then say so.

I can't figure out why my code is saying that all the numbers are prime except for multiples of 10, and even then if it is a multiple of 10 it is only showing 10 as a factor and not 2,5 etc ...any help is much appreciated!

```
for ($x = 3; $x <= 100; $x++) {
        $y = 2;
        do {
            $factors = array();
            if ( $x % $y == 0 and $x != $y) {
                $factors[] = $y;
            }
            $y++;
        }while ($y <= 10); 
        if (count($factors) == 0) {
            echo "$x is a prime number.<br />";
        }else {
            echo " The factors of $x are: "; foreach($factors as $factor) {echo "$factor ";} echo "<br />";
        }
    }
```

Results I get:

```
3 is a prime number.
4 is a prime number.
5 is a prime number. 
6 is a prime number.
```

Results I want:

```
3 is a prime number.
The factors of 4 are: 2
5 is a prime number.
The factors of 6 are: 2, 3
```

Comment: list few your expected number

Comment: Refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're resetting the factors array on each iteration of the `while` loop, rather than for each number.

Change it to something like:

```
for ($x = 3; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    $y = 2;
    $factors = array();
    do {            
        if ( $x % $y == 0 and $x != $y) {
            $factors[] = $y;
        }
        $y++;
    }while ($y <= 10); 
    if (count($factors) == 0) {
        echo "$x is a prime number.<br />";
    }else {
        echo " The factors of $x are: "; foreach($factors as $factor) {echo "$factor ";} echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please move the array initialization to outside loop. Hope that is the only issue.

```
        $factors = array();
        do {            
            if ( $x % $y == 0 and $x != $y) {
                $factors[] = $y;
            }
            $y++;
        } while ($y <= 10);
```

You can use implode() for getting it comma separated

```
for ($x = 3; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    $y = 2;
    $factors = array();
    do {

        if ( $x % $y == 0 and $x != $y) {
            $factors[] = $y;
        }
        $y++;
    } while ($y <= 10);
    if (count($factors) == 0) {
        echo "$x is a prime number.<br />";
    }else {
        echo " The factors of $x are: ".implode(', ', $factors)."<br />";
    }
}
```